# Is the fact that 100 kPa equals about 1 atmosphere accidental?

Tags: pressure, si-units, metrology

Typical atmosphere near sea level, in ambient conditions is around 100,000 pascals.

But the pascal, as the unit, is not defined through Earth atmospheric pressure. It's defined as one newton per square meter. The newton is $\rm{kg \: m}\over s^2$. So, $\rm[Pa] = [ {kg \over {m \: s^2}} ]$.

Nowadays, definitions of units are often fixed to various natural phenomena, but it wasn't quite so when they were being created.

The Second is an ancient unit, derived from a fraction of day, 1/86400
 of synodic day on Earth. The meter is derived from circumference of Earth, $10^{-7}$ the distance from north pole to equator. The kilogram came to be as mass of a cubic decimeter of water.

100,000 pascals, or 1 bar, though, is about the average atmospheric pressure at sea level. That's an awfully round number - while Earth atmosphere pressure doesn't seem to have anything in common with the rest of the "sources" of the other units.

Is this "round" value accidental, or am I missing some hidden relation?

Comment: It is not a completely round number, though: $$1\;\mathrm{atm}=101325\;\mathrm{Pa}\approx 101\;\mathrm {kPa}$$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but does "round" (in the sense of ***exactly divisible by some power of 10***) actually have any meaning in the context of "explaining" the natural world? I can certainly see that such a concept might be relevant if we were talking about ***some power of 2***, but apart from it's (pre-)historical significance as "most common number of digits on two (front) legs/arms in vertebrates", why should ***10*** be any more important than, say, ***9*** or ***11**?*

Comment: ...actually, I'd be quite prepared to believe that there might be some deep underlying significance to natural world ratios/values that are "round" in terms of being exact multiples of some power of ***3***, so  ***9*** might *really* be an important possibility above. And ***11*** might feasibly be "important" simply because it's a relatively small prime number.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Units are usually *chosen* such that they are powers of ten of "parent" units, or otherwise "round numbers" - like 10,000,000 meters being the distance from pole to equator; 100 Celsius degrees being the difference between freezing and boiling. It doesn't explain the natural world, it's just convenient to use. So most of "round" values of derived units you encounter in results of calculations are actually artifacts of these choices. But that's not always the case, plus when it is the case, the path the artifact arrived there is often non-obvious.

Comment: @SF.: Most long-established "everyday" units are chosen on the basis of ratios / bases ***other than 10*** (inch / foot / mile, second / minute / hour, ounce / pound / stone, etc.).  Factorisation is obviously important when setting ratios with those things, so maybe you could say there's some "fundamental (mathematical / geometric) significance" to numbers that come out "round" in those bases.  But base 10 is effectively "anthropocentric", so there's no inherent significance to "10 to the power **n**" values (unlike "**2** to the power n", say, for *inverse square law* contexts).

Comment: *Am I missing some hidden relation ?* - Go to my profile page and read my motto.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "Most long-established "everyday" units are chosen on the basis of ratios / bases other than 10" - Maybe in your USA. Most of the world is metric, and uses metric system for "everyday" units.

Comment: @Lucian: One nanocentury is $\pi$ seconds, to within 0.5%.

Comment: @SF. okay you can choose one case to be the "round" multiple like pole to eq, but then the distance from pole to Z would be 1463 meters. Or you can select water's boiling temp to be 100 then Y's boiling temp would be 247. so.. it should work in some cases but I'm not sure how common that would be?

Comment: @EralpB: This is if you analyze natural phenomena. Where it comes to engineering, where you deal with results of arbitrary decisions: dimensions chosen to be round numbers, helpful choices of "round" masses etc. (example of the latter: take your collection of kitchen vessels - pots, skillets, strainers, plates etc, and weigh them. You'll be surprised they have pretty "round" weights!)

Comment: @SF.: I said most ***long-established*** units! The metric system is a relative parvenu in the grand scheme of things (and *still* doesn't extend to everyday multiples such as days in a week, degrees in a circle, etc.). Besides which most of its more familiar "base units" (degree Celsius,  gram, metre, etc.) are effectively either arbitrary or geocentric/anthropocentric. So there's no reason to expect multiples of things like that to have "universal" significance beyond that implied by Benford's Law (which applies equally in *any* base).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, systems of ancient egypt are longer-established. And they certainly were "everyday" units back in the day. Besides Benford's Law, there's plain psychology of preferring to pick round numbers when making arbitrary choice. Doorways being 180cm tall, as opposed to 176 or 181, shops selling wares in packages of 1kg as opposed to 947 or 1111 gram, etc. And then you arrive at results like average load per axis of a truck being a round number, because volume of the trailer is a round number so it fits a round number of items (dimensions being round) weighing a round number.

Comment: @SF.:  Given that theoretical physicist and pure mathematicians are much concerned with things like [sphere packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing) and [Penrose tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) (where powers of 10 are about as relevant as powers of 123), I wouldn't make too much of multiples/powers of 10 favoured in areas (pun intended! :) such as "bulk" sale or  transportation (if anything, they'd tend to favour powers of 2 simply because of the inverse square law as it relates to areas or volumes).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, I'm no theoretical physicist or pure mathematician. I'm an engineer. Nature doesn't favor powers of 10. Engineering (human creations) do.

Comment: @SF.:  I'd consider something like the Eiffel Tower to be a prime example of "engineering", but I seriously doubt any of the lengths or ratios used in its construction have any meaningful relationship with the number 10. It's simply not an inherently important number outside of the fact that all advanced countries now use it as their base for counting. Which itself only arises from the "happenstance" fact that "non-pentadactyl" vertebrates (with other than five "digits" on each limb) practically all got wiped out  in one or more mass extinctions.

Comment: The height of the Eiffel Tower as projected was 300m sharp. This [changed over time](https://www.toureiffel.paris/en/news/history-and-culture/300-330-meters-story-towers-height) as things were added on top, but the original 300m was an arbitrary choice of a round number.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is a coincidence. There's nothing about the atmosphere that would make it have a nice relationship with the Earth's rotation or diameter, or the fact that water is plentiful on the surface.

On the other hand, it's important to note that the coincidence isn't quite as remarkable as you note, because of a version of [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law). Given absolutely zero prior knowledge about how much air there is in the atmosphere, our guess about the value of the atmospheric pressure would have to be evenly distributed over many orders of magnitude. This is akin to throwing a dart at a piece of log-scale graph paper:

[image]

Note that the squares in which the coordinates start with $1.\:{{.}{.}{.}}$ are bigger than the others, so they're rather more likely to catch the dart. A similar (weaker) effect makes the probability of the second digit being 0 be 12% instead of the naive 10%.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64889/discussion-on-answer-by-emilio-pisanty-is-100-kpa-equal-about-1-atmosphere-accid).

Answer (score 26):

To expand on @EmilioPisanty's answer. The [original definition of the meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre#History_of_definition) was:

> one ten-millionth of the distance between the North Pole and the Equator[.]

The [original definition of the gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram#History) was:

> The word gramme was adopted by the French National Convention in its 1795 decree revising the metric system as replacing the gravet introduced in 1793. Its definition remained that of the weight (poids) of a cubic centimetre of water.

And the [original definition of a second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second#History_of_definition) can be traced back to the sexagesimal counting system of the Babylonians and the length of a day. Thus the original definition of a second is $\frac{1\operatorname{day}}{24 \times 60 \times 60}$, on average. Roughly speaking, then, we can trace the value of $1$ Pascal back to the radius of the Earth, the rotational period of the Earth, and the density of water. There is no reason to expect the pressure of the atmosphere at sea level to be particularly closely related to any of those, since that will depend on the composition of the Earth (the mass dictated by the Earth's material composition [balance of silicates vs iron/nickel]), its radius, and the temperature at its surface (which depends on the sun, planet's albedo, etc.), the strength of the Earth's magnetic field, and how energetic the solar winds stripping the atmosphere away are.

At any rate, in terms of the original definitions, the Pascal is given by:
$$1\operatorname{Pa} \equiv \left(\frac{729 \pi^2}{39,062,500,000}\right)\frac{\rho_{\mathrm{water}} R_{\mathrm{Earth}}^2}{T_{\mathrm{day}}^2},$$
and we have no reason to expect that the atmospheric pressure at sea level to be particularly closely related to any of those variables, especially given the interference of other factors in fixing the air pressure at sea level.

Note that the air pressure at sea level can also change. Consider Venus, for example. It's a smaller planet, but the combination of being closer to the sun and a strong greenhouse effect means its atmosphere is incredibly heavy. The [pressure at the surface of Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Venus) is $9.3\operatorname{MPa}$, or about $92$ times greater than atmospheric pressure here on Earth.

Looking at how the temperature of Earth, the composition of its atmosphere, and the solar output have [all changed over time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleoclimatology), I would be surprised to learn that the sea level pressure of the atmosphere has been stable to better than a factor of $2$ over its whole history.

Edit: I found a reference to one [reconstruction of ancient atmospheric pressure](http://www.nature.com/ngeo/journal/v9/n6/full/ngeo2713.html).

> Here, we calculate absolute Archaean barometric pressure using the size distribution of gas bubbles in basaltic lava flows that solidified at sea level $\sim 2.7 \operatorname{Gyr}$ in the Pilbara Craton, Australia. Our data indicate a surprisingly low surface atmospheric pressure of $P_{\mathrm{atm}} = 0.23 \pm 0.23\ (2\sigma) \operatorname{bar}$, and combined with previous studies suggests $\sim 0.5 \operatorname{bar}$ as an upper limit to late Archaean $P_{\mathrm{atm}}$

Comment: I have asked a question over at the Earth Science StackExchange for a paleoclimate reconstruction of the Earth's atmospheric pressure at sea level.

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/is-there-a-reconstruction-of-paleoclimate-sea-level-air-pressure

Comment: Originally, they wanted to define the meter from the length of the [seconds pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconds_pendulum). So that would mean $1\operatorname{m} \equiv g \left(\frac{1\operatorname{s}}{\pi}\right) ^2$ where $g$ is the standard gravity. You can write your answer again using that definition of the meter. The fact that the old definition with the seconds pendulum gives $0.994$ times the other definition with the North-Pole-to-Equator distance, must be another coincidence. I think they changed to the latter definition because $0.994$ is so close to $1$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Interesting. That would remove one of the coincidences, and pressure is more tightly tied to $g$ than any of the other quantities mentioned. I think that the temperature coincidence can't be avoided, though it can be argued that temperature and pressure near water's triple point is essential for life, but that leaves a wide range of pressures, as [this graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water#/media/File:Phase_diagram_of_water_simplified.svg) shows.

Comment: Actually, that definition of the meter just piles on more coincidences, including two more factors of $R_{\mathrm{Earth}}$, two factors of $M_{\mathrm{Earth}}$, and two factors of $G$.

Comment: Hm, you should express the Venus athmosphere pressure in terms of Venus-Pascals, i.e., density of the most prevalent liquid, radius of the planet, length of a venusian day

Comment: That reference is for only the atmosphere 2.7 billion years ago. For the eras of the dinosaurs, it makes a lot more sense if the atmosphere was a lot higher pressure.

Answer (score -4):

No it is **not** coincidence:

It is because units for mass, force and pressure have been **choosen** such that common ratios of those units (density of water $\rho_{Water}$, gravitational acceleration on earth $g$; pressure unit $1 at$) have values that are powers of 10.
(Further improvements in measurement changed those values a little bit later on; especially $g$; that's why the values are not exactly $1.000\times 10^n$).

- 1 at is **defined** as the pressure of 10m water column
  reference: ["A technical atmosphere (symbol: at) is a non-SI unit of pressure equal to **one kilogram-force per square centimeter**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_atmosphere)
  (The [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technische_Atmosph%C3%A4re) mentions the 10m water column; which is equivalent to weight of 1kg per cm²)
- The density of water is **not by coincidence** (but by early definitions of unit of mass kg) almost exactly 1000kg/m³
- The gravitational acceleration $g$ is **not by coincidence** (but by early definitions of unit of force N) approximately 10N/kg (more exactly about 9.81N/kg; even more exact value depends on the place on earth (especially latitude)).

Putting that together you get:

roughly:
$1 at \approx 10 \times 1000kg/m³ \times 10N/kg = 100000 N/m² = 100000Pa$

more exact:
$1 at = 10 \times 1000kg/m³ \times 9.81N/kg =  98100 N/m² = 98100Pa$
or
$1 Pa = 1019 \times10^{-5}at$

---

**EDIT:**
I'm referring above to the value of 1 **at** (called "technical atmosphere") not the standard atmosphere.

Note that the title of the original question is ambiguous as it just mentions "1 atmosphere".

Comment: You're confusing a "Technical atmosphere" ($\mathrm{at}$) for a "standard atmosphere" ($\mathrm{atm}$). The former was almost certainly chosen because it is nearly equal to the latter, and the latter being nearly $10^5\operatorname{Pa}$ is a coincidence.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_(unit)

Comment: No, the atmosphere was defined as the average air pressure at sea level at the latitude of Paris. It happens to be about 10 meters of water.

Comment: @Sean E. Lake and Pieter: [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technische_Atmosph%C3%A4re) says that the technical atmosphere was **defined** to be the pressure caused by 10m water. (**Why** it was done so is a completely different story).

Comment: @Curd Why'd they choose $10\operatorname{m}$ and not 11, 9, or 1?

Comment: of course because 10 is a power of 10. 11 and 9 are not. 1 would have been ok too (it's also a power of 10).

Comment: And you'd be wrong, @Curd. The technical atmosphere is chosen as a unit that is near the standard atmosphere that is convenient to calibrate. Thus, if $1\operatorname{atm}$ were about half of what it is, the technical atmosphere would be $5\operatorname{m}$ instead of 10.

Comment: @Sean E. Lake: or it might just not have been called "atmosphere" but still 10m water column could have been used as very convenient unit for pressure! (because of the importance of  water towers and water pipes at different levels) How do you want to know how people had decided when nature was so different? That belongs rather in science fiction.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing the references which support your **not by coincidence** statements above.

Comment: I mentioned the German WIiipedia; but you can have also a look at the English Wikipedia (it just doesn't mention the 10m watre column, but still the relationship to the weight of 1kg per cm²; wich is equivalent if you assume density of water to be 1000kg/m³): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_atmosphere

Comment: BTW: I agree completely to Sean E. Lake that what I was stating does not apply to the standard atmosphere (which is as I see it now probably more what OP was interested in); on the other hand OP uses the word  atmosphere as unit for pressure, which made me think he means 1 at (technical atmosphere)).

Comment: Maybe the question should have been: Why is the value for standard atmosphere so close to the value of technical atmosphere? That's coincidence.

Comment: I've dealt with pressure quite a bit in school.  I've _never_ heard "atmosphere" as a unit given as anything besides a standard atmosphere.  TBH this is the first I've ever heard of a "technical atmosphere".  It's not nearly as common as a standard atmosphere.  If hey meant technical atmosphere, the question should ask about it.  (Wikipedia for example has the page [Atmosphere(unit)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_(unit)) which is about atm, not at.

Comment: @JMac: for me it's the other way round: although I know *standard atmosphere* as the reference pressure of *standard conditions* I've never ever seen it ever used as **unit** (e.g. like "the pressure of gas in this container is 2.34 _standard_ atmospheres"). See this old [Manometer](https://de.dreamstime.com/stockfoto-altes-manometer-mit-wei%C3%9Fer-skala-image58226728): kgf means "kilogram force", i.e. unit used here also is **at** (not atm)

Comment: @Curd I've seen things referred to as "2 atm" (usually called "two atmospheres"), 10 atm, etc, in a lot of engineering texts.  I've not once seen a "technical atmosphere".  Maybe it's a localization thing; but it's never used in the North American or International versions of the textbooks I had.

Comment: @JMac: maybe it's a American/European thing. I guess **at** in Europe was in former times as common as **psi** in America.